# Use the Calendar API without human interaction

Tags: python, google-calendar-api, google-workspace, google-api-python-client, service-accounts

I am trying to get events from a Google Calendar without prompting consent page to the user.
I have used a service account for this (json file with all the data)

But when I ran the script I am getting this

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import googleapiclient.discovery
import time
import jwt

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = '/Users/user/Downloads/XXXXXXXX.json'

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

page_token = None
calendar_list_entry = service.calendarList().get(calendarId='XXXXXXXXXXX@group.calendar.google.com').execute()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Users/user/Downloads/blender.py", line 16, in 
> calendar_list_entry = service.calendarList().get(calendarId='XXXXXXX@group.calendar.google.com').execute()
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 131, in positional_wrapper
> return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 937, in execute
> raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList/XXXXXXXX%40group.calendar.google.com?alt=json returned "**Not Found**". **Details: "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'notFound', 'message': 'Not Found'}]"**>`

Answer (score 1):

In order to use Google Calendar with a serice account you must have set up domain wide deligation to your [workspace account](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/concepts/domain)

you are getting a HttpError 404 when requesting error message because you have not properly delegated the service account to a user on your domain with access to that calendar so the service account doesnt have access.

In the code sample below take a close look at the line `credentials = credentials.create_delegated(user_email)` this is the user on your domain which you would like to delegate the service accounts permissions to

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

# Email of the Service Account
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = '<some-id>@developer.gserviceaccount.com'

# Path to the Service Account's Private Key file
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = '/path/to/<public_key_fingerprint>-privatekey.p12'

def create_directory_service(user_email):
    """Build and returns an Calendar service object authorized with the service accounts
    that act on behalf of the given user.

    Args:
      user_email: The email of the user. Needs permissions to access the calendar APIs.
    Returns:
      Calendar service object.
    """

    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_p12_keyfile(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH,
        'notasecret',
        scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'])

    credentials = credentials.create_delegated(user_email)

    return build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
```

Json key file. There is a sample for the library using the json key file [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/main/samples/service_account/tasks.py) it just doesnt include the delegation you will need to add that line.

Remember service accounts only work with google workspace domains.  It will not work with a standard Google calendar account.